# Calling a randomized algorithm iteratively, receiving the same result each call

Tags: ruby, random, graph-algorithm

I am attempting to implement Kargers min-cut algorithm. The algorithm is a randomized algorithm that you should run `(n(logn))^2` times to be confident you've found the minimum cut. I've done a novice's job at implementing this algorithm in-place in Ruby:

```
def karger(graph)
#graph will be an array
#each element of graph is an array
#these subarrays are of the form [[4], 43, 23, 1, 67]
#where the zeroth element is the vertex label
#the other elements represent edges to other vertices.
  while graph.length > 2
    #u & v are the indices of two random vertices that will be merged together
    u = rand(0...graph.length)
    v = rand(0...graph.length)
    #while loop ensures u != v
    while v == u
      u = rand(0...graph.length)
      v = rand(0...graph.length)
    end
    #merge u & v into a single vertex, 
    graph[u] += graph[v][1...graph[v].length]
    graph[u][0].concat(graph[v][0])
    graph.delete_at(v)
  end
  #this nested block eliminates self loops on the two remaining superveticies
  graph.each do |z|
    z.each do |x|
      unless x.class == Array
        if z[0].include?(x)
          z.delete(x)
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return (graph[0].length)-1 #-1 since the first element of both subarrays is the vertex   label
end
```

My problem is that when I try to create a block or loop to run the algorithm the necessary `(nlog(n))^2` times, every single cut is the same value. So if the first call of `karger()` produces a cut of 2, then every single call after that will return 2 as well. However, if I call `karger()` manually, just pressing cntrl R in textmate, I will get a variation in my results. The first time I run it on a certain input, I get a cut of 5, the next time, 2. Thus my attempt at generating a massive sample of `karger()` calls, and finding the minimum result does not work, because I will just have a massive sample of 2's or 5's or whatever. If I run the block that calls `karger()` `(nlog(n))^2` times, I get different answers, depending on what the first call of `karger()` returns, since every other call returns the same result.

Hope that's clear.

Here's a sample graph:

```
testgraph1 = [[[1],2,2,3], [[2],1,1,3,4,5], [[3],1,2,4], [[4],2,3], [[5],2]]
```

---

EDIT:

I thought it might be helpful if I added the method I've used to iteratively call the function:

```
def kargeriterate(graph)
  n = graph.flatten.length
  min = graph.flatten.length
  ((n)*(Math.log(n)))**2.to_i.times do |z|
      a = karger(graph)
      puts a  #this puts is here just to see each output
      if a < min
        min = a
      end
    end
  return min
end
```

Comment: in the interest of full disclosure. Since you're a new user and this is your first question. Is this a homework problem? Not that that's necessarily an issue, but you might want to do that to avoid being voted down.

Comment: depends on what you mean by homework. It is for a coursera class on algorithms. This is not homework in the sense that you are helping me receive a grade from a class i've paid tuition for, I am just interested in algorithms, and IMO this is the best way to learn it for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods like `delete` and `delete_at` modify their argument in place. Since everything is passed by value in ruby, this means that the second (and third, fourth, fifth etc) time you call `karger` you're doing so on the already processed graph, so the method doesn't do anything.

It looks like you modify the arrays nested inside `graph` as well as `graph` itself, so doing `graph=graph.dup` at the start of your `karger` method wouldn't be enough. There isn't a standard deep copy built-in to ruby, but an easy way to achieve this is to dump and deserialize your object:

```
def karger(graph)
  graph = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(graph))
  ...
end
```